# Short circuit in JS stopping on first input

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, short-circuiting

I'm having some problems trying to use short circuiting on a web page I am making.

I am trying to use

```
document.webkitExitFullscreen() || document.mozCancelFullScreen() || document.exitFullScreen();
```

But it seems to stop on the first try, despite that I would have though it would continue after the first argument comes up as undefined.

If I simply type in

```
document.mozCancelFullScreen()
```

then it works fine

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rINs1kR.png]

I was wondering if anyone could point me to what I'm doing wrong here
The screenshot is taken in firefox btw.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you call `document.webkitExitFullScreen()` in Firefox, what does it return? Just there inside the console, enter the code, and see what the result is. If it returns `true`, then that is why it short circuits your ors.

Comment: What exactly do you expect. The code you provide is the fullsreen API for exiting fullscreen and your image shows a screen that has just entered fullscreen

Comment: using it without parenthesis returns undefined

Comment: @zer00ne I'm trying to get it to exit fullscreen, When I call the code above when clicking the yellow X, it returns document.webkitExitFullScreen() is not a function

Comment: @krillgar (here is simply calling  the webkit version)[http://i.imgur.com/xgxeYFh.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is trying to **call** `document.webkitExitFullscreen` and if it returns a falsy value, **call** `document.mozCancelFullScreen`, etc.

But if `document.webkitExitFullscreen` itself is `undefined` you'll get an error trying to call it, and the code will stop running at that point.

Perhaps:

```
var exitFullScreen = document.webkitExitFullscreen || document.mozCancelFullScreen || document.exitFullScreen;
if (exitFullScreen) {
    exitFullScreen.call(document); // Just `exitFullScreen();` may work as well
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
["webkitExitFullscreen", "mozCancelFullScreen", "exitFullScreen"].some(function(name) {
    if (document[name]) {
        document[name]();
        return true;
    }
});
```

...which avoids the whole "do I need `call` or not?" issue.

Comment: @user3232009: You probably couldn't when you posted that comment, there's a 15-minute blockout. You can now, by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Glad that helped!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're already calling the function, so if it doesn't exist, you get an error.
You coudl try something like:

```
(document.webkitExitFullscreen || document.mozCancelFullScreen || document.exitFullScreen)();
```